# Wagtail Contact Form but with a Template

Tags: django, wagtail

So I have seen the tutorials and they are suggesting I make a Contact page so it is creatable within the admin section of WagtailAdmin but I don't want that.

I already have a pre created contact Template page and I don't want to use the Wagtail way to auto generate form elements. Is there a way in which I can use my custom HTML template instead of having an auto generated one that I have to create within WagtailAdmin?

I just want to be able to receive the input via a View and then process the data, is there a way in which I can accomplish this?

Comment: Wagtail is based on Django as you know, so yes, you can use your own view with your own template. Have you worked with Django before, without Wagtail?

Answer (score 0):

On a Wagtail page, [the `serve` method](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/pages/model_recipes.html#overriding-the-serve-method) is equivalent to a Django function, so you can use it for any code that you would normally put in a view, including form processing:

```
class FormPage(Page):

    def serve(self, request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = MyDjangoForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                result = form.save()
                return render(request, 'myapp/thankyou.html', {
                    'page': self,
                    'result': result,
                })
        else:
            form = MyDjangoForm()

        return render(request, 'myapp/form.html', {
            'page': self,
            'form': form,
        })
```

See https://github.com/gasman/wagtail-form-example/commits/master for a complete example (written for Wagtail 1.x, so module imports won't be up to date, but the principle remains the same).